# Yuengling Bottles for Homebrew?

Tags: bottling

Will Yuengling bottles work well to bottle? I don't care about the label, just that the bottle is strong and will take a non twist-off cap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When I ran out of bottles a few brews ago, I decided to use a couple of Yuengling bottles to have somewhere to put the last 24 ounces of beer. I didn't really care if they didn't work out, but I have to say they were even bigger failures than I'd imagined. The twist-top grooves on the bottles didn't allow for a satisfactory seal, and they both ended up popping partly off when secondary fermentation kicked in.

Lesson learned: avoid using them if you can.

Comment: Speaking from experience, I agree that it is extremely difficult to cap twist-top bottles.  I had one batch where about 6 were twist-tops, used a bench capper, and every one of the bottles were flat, the CO2 leaked right out.  I would recommend not using them.

Answer (score 1):

Yuengling bottles will work fine. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "will take a non twist-off cap" Because if your using a typical capper you shouldn't be capping on twist-off bottles.

One issue with Yuengling is that their bottles are often green, and if you don't keep them clear of the light once filled you will easily get skunky beer. Just something to keep in mind.

**Edit:**

Looks like I misread the question.

Regarding capping on bottles that *DO* have twist off tops - It works best if you use a bench capper. A normal hand capper can easily break the glass off the top of the bottle.

You will be more subject to leaks, but it's not impossible.

Comment: Ok I am using a normal capper, so I can't use bottles that are twist offs?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest against using a Yuengling bottle for two reasons.  First, it's twist off.  Second, it's green.

Regarding the first point; from my understanding when you use a traditional homebrew capper it will not seal a twist off bottle well.  It ends up letting air in which oxygenates the beer.

For the second point, light entering bottles reacts with compounds in the hops and creates a "skunked" beer.  A darker bottle will block more light than a lighter bottle.

That being said, I think it really depends on the style of beer being made.  If you are brewing a light and/or hoppy beer that should be consumed relatively soon the bottle would have less of an affect on the finished product than a big malt bomb that you would leave in the bottle for a while.

I still don't think I would risk the twist offs though because I'd be worried about not having a good enough seal and letting all of the carbonation out.